# How to set control points of a bezier curve to bend a line?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I want to draw a slightly bent line using bezier curve.

This is the bezier curve function:

`function bezierCurve(controlPoint1, controlPoint2, line) { }`

I don't know how to set control points to achieve a slightly bent line for any line.

I tried to find the perpendicular point of this line:

```
function Line(a, b) {

  let mid = [(a[0] + b[0]) / 2,
             (a[1] + b[1]) / 2];

  let dX = b[0] - a[0],
      dY = b[1] - a[1];

  this.perpPoint = (y) => {
    let x1 = mid[0],
        y1 = mid[1],
        x;

    if (dX === 0 || dY === 0) {
      x = y;
      y = y1;

      return [x, y];
    }

    let m = dX / dY;

    let perpendicularM = - 1 / m;

    // y - y1 = m(x - x1)
    // x = (y - y1) / m + x1

    x = (y - y1) / m + x1;

    return [x, y];
  };
```

And use that somehow to find the points just above the midpoint of the line as control points, but didn't work.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried

Comment: Just in case [here's a reference](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

> `function bezierCurve(controlPoint1, controlPoint2, line) { }`

Suggest that the curve is a cubic bezier (two control points) the function you give looks like its only finding a point mid way and offset some fixed amount. you will need more control over where the point is in relationship to the line.

### Perpendicular offset from line.

The following function will give you a little more control letting you specifty where along the line you want the point and how far that point should be from the line.

The argument `along` and `dist` are fractions of a line such the `along = 0.5` is halfway and `dist = 0.2` is 1/5th the length of the line away. `dist > 0` and the point is offset to the right of the line `dist < 0` and the offset is to the left (Y axis pointing down)

```
function pointFromLine(along, dist, p1, p2, res = {}) {
    const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
    const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
    res.x = p1.x + dx * along - dy * dist;
    res.y = p1.y + dy * along + dx * dist;
    return res;
}
```

To find the mid point 1/5th the line length away from the center

```
const p1 = {x: 10, y: 10};
const p2 = {x: 510, y: 310};
const offset = pointFromLine(0.5, 0.2, p1, p2);
```

To find two control point for a cubic bezier.

```
const p1 = {x: 10, y: 10};
const p2 = {x: 510, y: 310};
const cp1 = pointFromLine(0.333, 0.2, p1, p2);     // 1/3rd dist from start
const cp2 = pointFromLine(1 - 0.333, 0.2, p1, p2); // equal dist (1/3rd) from end of line
```

### Usage example

The following snippet show the function used to create a symmetrical curve for a cubic bezier. Move the slider to control the dist along the line and the dist offset from the line

```js
    function pointFromLine(along, dist, p1, p2, res = {}) {
        const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
        const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
        res.x = p1.x + dx * along - dy * dist;
        res.y = p1.y + dy * along + dx * dist;
        return res;
    }   

    const p1 = {x: 40, y: 40};
    const p2 = {x: 160, y: 160};
    const cp1 ={x: 0, y: 0};
    const cp2 ={x: 0, y: 0};        
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    update();
    function drawPoint(p) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    function drawLine(p1, p2) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    function drawCubicBezier(p1, p2, cp1, cp2) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        drawLine(p1,cp1);
        drawLine(p2,cp2);
        drawPoint(p1);
        drawPoint(p2);
        drawPoint(cp1);
        drawPoint(cp2);
    }
    
    alongIn.addEventListener("input", update);
    distIn.addEventListener("input", update);
    
    function update() {
        const a = alongIn.value * 1;
        const d = distIn.value * 1;
        info.textContent = `Along: ${a.toFixed(2)} Offset: ${d.toFixed(2)}`
        
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
        drawCubicBezier(
            p1, 
            p2, 
            pointFromLine(a , d, p1, p2, cp1),
            pointFromLine(1 - a, d, p1, p2, cp2)
        );
    }
```

```css
   
   canvas {
       border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
   Dist along: <input id="alongIn" type="range" min="-1" max="2" step="0.01" value="0.3"/>
   Dist out: <input id="distIn" type="range" min="-1" max="2" step="0.01" value="0.3"/>
   <div id="info"> </div>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
```