# JavaScript Bezier curve compute offset distance

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cubic-bezier

I am drawing a `Bezier curve` on drag `cp1` and `cp2` control points.

To draw `Bezier Curve` using `D3js`.

`Bezier Curve` four control points are `line1`,`cp1`,`cp2` and `line2`.

I follow below steps to draw a `Bezier curve`

1)`Moveto(Line1)`

2)`BezierCurve(Cp1 Cp2 Line2)`

```
pathPoints = d3.path();
pathPoints.moveTo(allPaths[0].l1.x,allPaths[0].l1.y);
pathPoints.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x,cp1.y,cp2.x,cp2.y,item.l2.x,item.l2.y);
```

When I drag `cp1` from the  mouse events I get positions cp1.

Now I know `line1` and `cp1` how do I compute `dist`.

I am using reference code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659008/how-to-set-control-points-of-a-bezier-curve-to-bend-a-line)

Using `pointFromLine` function  I get `cp1` and `cp2`. I dont know `dist`.

I also have another function calculatePoint to get `cp1` and `cp2` on a `line1`.

```js
cp1 = calculatePoint(item.l1,item.l2,50);
d1 = hypo(item.l1,cp1);
cp2 = calculatePoint(item.l2,item.l1,50);
d2 = hypo(item.l2,cp2);
```

`d1` and `d2` after finding the Euclidian Distance is not equal to `50`.Is it correct Euclidian distance between `line1` and `cp1` give distance `d1`.

```js
function pointFromLine(along, dist, p1, p2, res = {}) {
  const dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  const dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  res.x = p1.x + dx * along - dy * dist;
  res.y = p1.y + dy * along + dx * dist;
  return res;
}

function calculatePoint(a,b,distance)
{

  // a. calculate the vector from o to g:
  let vectorX = b.x - a.x;
  let vectorY = b.y - a.y;
  // b. calculate the proportion of hypotenuse
  let factor = distance / Math.sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);

  // c. factor the lengths
  vectorX *= factor;
  vectorY *= factor;

  // d. calculate and Draw the new vector,
  // return new Point((int)(a.X + vectorX), (int)(a.Y + vectorY));
  return {x:a.x + vectorX,y:a.y + vectorY}
}

function hypo(p0,p1){
  return Math.round(Math.sqrt((p1.x-p0.x)** 2  + (p1.y-p0.y)** 2 ))
}
```

I did not understand `distance along` and `distance offset` and how to compute if I know `line1` and `cp1`

In the refernce [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-b%25C3%25A9zier-curves)

`(4/3)*tan(pi/8) = 4*(sqrt(2)-1)/3`

I am not sure what is 'n'. I know cp1 and line1.

Answer (score 0):

The distance parameter in `calculatePoint` seems not the same as the `dist` parameter in `pointFromLine`. In `calculatePoint`, distance is the total distance from `a` to the calculated point, while in `pointFromLine`, `dist` is the perpendicular distance from the line at the calculated point.

If you want to calculate `cp1` and `cp2` such that they are **50** units away from `line1` and `line2` respectively, you should use `pointFromLine` instead of `calculatePoint`.

Modified in function *calculatePoint*;

```
cp1 = pointFromLine(0.5, 50, item.l1, item.l2);
d1 = hypo(item.l1, cp1);
cp2 = pointFromLine(0.5, 50, item.l2, item.l1);
d2 = hypo(item.l2, cp2);
```

Here, **0.5** is the proportion of the line from `line1` to `line2` where you want to calculate `cp1` and `cp2`. If you want `cp1` and `cp2` to be at the midpoints of `line1` and `line2` respectively, you should use **0.5**. If you want them to be at other positions, you should adjust this proportion accordingly.

*If you still get distances that are not equal to **50**, it might be due to the way you are drawing your Bezier curve. The `bezierCurveTo` function in **D3.js** creates a cubic Bezier curve from the current point to *(x, y)* using *(cp1x, cp1y)* as the control point at the beginning of the curve and *(cp2x, cp2y)* as the control point at the end of the curve. If the curve does not pass through `cp1` and `cp2` exactly, the calculated points will not be 50 units away from `line1` and `line2`.

> I did not understand this point *"In calculatePoint, distance is the total distance from a to the calculated point, while in pointFromLine, dist is the perpendicular distance from the line at the calculated point."*

**Clarification:** In the `calculatePoint`, the `distance` parameter represents the total distance from point `a` (the starting point of the line segment) to the new point that the function calculates. This is calculated by scaling the vector from `a` to `b` (the end point of the line segment) by the ratio of `distance` to the length of the vector from `a` to `b`.

On the other hand, in the `pointFromLine`, the `dist` parameter represents the perpendicular distance from the line at the calculated point to the new point. This is calculated by adding a vector to the point on the line at the position specified by `along` that is perpendicular to the line and has a length of `dist`.

In other words, `calculatePoint` calculates a point along a line segment by scaling the vector from the start of the line segment to the end of the line segment, while `pointFromLine` calculates a point along a line segment by adding a vector perpendicular to the line at a specified position on the line segment.

The concept of perpendicular distance is used in the `pointFromLine` because it calculates a point along a line segment that is a certain distance away from the line at a specified position on the line segment. This is different from the concept of total distance used in the `calculatePoint`, which calculates a point along a line segment that is a certain total distance from the start of the line segment.

Comment: I did not understand  this point "In calculatePoint, distance is the total distance from a to the calculated point, while in pointFromLine, dist is the perpendicular distance from the line at the calculated point."